# SQL Server Max Memory not limiting use of RAM

Tags: sql-server-2008, memory

I would like your input on this. I have a sql server 2008r2 Ent. Ed. 64bit with 16 cores and 64GB RAM. There is one instance of SQL server patched fully as of 20111014.

The max ram is set to 60000MB. Amount of free ram is 0 according to task manager after a few days online.

If I change the max ram to below 53GB it will after a few days to stabilize and have some free ram.

It is the sql process that does allocate the ram according to task manager. How do i come to terms with what the problem really is? It goes without saying that i did alot of testing already but havn't solved this to my liking yet. and ohh we do not get the typical memory starvation lagging when the available ram is down to 0 free.

**Update 1:**

Inspired by another Q/A related to RAM on this page https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7062/2744 . I used these two to see what the RAM is being used for.

```
SELECT TOP ( 10 )
        [type] AS [Memory Clerk Type] ,
        SUM(single_pages_kb) AS [SPA Mem, Kb]
FROM    sys.dm_os_memory_clerks
GROUP BY [type]
ORDER BY SUM(single_pages_kb) DESC
OPTION  ( RECOMPILE ) ;

SELECT  DB_NAME(database_id) AS [Database Name] ,
        COUNT(*) * 8 / 1024.0 AS [Cached Size (MB)]
FROM    sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
--WHERE   database_id > 4 -- system databases
--        AND database_id <> 32767 -- ResourceDB
GROUP BY DB_NAME(database_id)
ORDER BY [Cached Size (MB)] DESC
OPTION  ( RECOMPILE ) ;
```

The amount used shown by these are 
first select 7948432    Kb
second one 44030,57812  MB
that is a total of about 52GB used by sql server... so where did the rest of my RAM go? :-)
Task manager show right now cached 363, available 401, free 40 and sqlservr.exe has Memory private set 64 459 656. Max Ram set to 60000MB as before.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

SQL Servers max memory setting defines the limits for buffer pool usage only. There will be variable but significant allocations required over and above that limit.

[Jonathan Kehayias's](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2009/07/07/understanding-the-vas-reservation-aka-memtoleave-in-sql-server.aspx), [Christian Bolton](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/christian/archive/2008/01/07/sql-server-memtoleave-vas-and-64-bit.aspx) and [John Samson](http://www.johnsansom.com/sql-server-memory-configuration-determining-memtoleave-settings/#axzz1edYFoxbs) have level 300/400 posts on the topic. [Brent Ozar](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/09/sysadmins-guide-microsoft-sql-server-memory/) has an easier to read article that might be a better place to start.

Also related: [SQL Server 2008 R2 “Ghost Memory”](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7060/sql-server-2008-r2-ghost-memory)

Comment: yes, I agree that it limits the buffer pool only. Thank you for the bookmarks I will look into them.

Comment: I am reading up on those links and there are some good stuff there def. I will update my question with what I find out. I also feel relifed that i have the number to Max Pizzeria readily available... I wonder if they do homedelivery?

Answer (score 16):

As said Buffer pool and procedure cache are about the only things which are controlled by max server memory.  There are lots of other things within SQL Server that can eat up memory beyond that limit.  They include (but are not limited to):

- Database Mail
- SQLCLR
- Extended Stored Procedures
- The binaries them selves
- SQL Mail
- SSIS
- SSAS
- SSRS

Comment: Of the above mentioned we use the binaries ofc and ssis on this server.

Comment: What other software is installed on the server?  And I mean anything. MPIO drivers, Flash drive drivers, backup software, anti-virus, sys-internals, etc.

Comment: The server is pretty clean and newly installed but ofc we do have some there. I will try to get a complete list put together at the end of this week. Short and from my memory... we do have an iodrive(dell), mcafee, processexplorer on desktop, iometer, treesize...

Comment: The FusionIO driver needs a lot of memory to work with. That's probably taking a lot of it.

Comment: Is it possible to prove this? Or to configure it to use less RAM? Sofar it seems to release RAM when it has to and i havn't noticed any downsides but just incase we have to increase amount of ssis packages I am concerned at what might happen with RAM usage.

Comment: FusionIO has documented this on their site and docs.  If you can't find it, give them a call they'll point you to it.

Answer (score 3):

From SQL 2012 onwards, single_pages_kb got replaced by pages_kb in that DMV. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175019.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

So if you want to run the query included in the question, on a 2012+ server, remove the single_ string.

Comment: Thanks. I converted it to page_size_in_bytes, but that wasn't the same.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx

To reduce the max server memory you may need to restart SQL Server to release the memory.

My understanding is that if a page in the buffer pool hasn't been written to disk, it will not be released until it is.

Does lowering the max memory setting cause SQL Server to flush out dirty pages?

He could monitor the buffer manager in perfmon to verify that.
Perfmon -> SQLServer:Buffer Manager : Database Pages

Comment: You "may" need to restart SQL Server.  It's not always required. Do you know the conditions under which a restart is or isn't required to release memory?

Comment: I would edit these details into your existing answer and delete this one.  Perhaps mrdenny can answer your question about flushing dirty pages.

Comment: Correct, SQL can't release a memory page while it is dirty (has been written to).  Every time the system checkpoints the dirty pages are written to disk.  I don't believe that changing max server memory causes a checkpoint to happen.

Comment: Restarting the instance to change memory settings could be a big mistake. While changing the memory settings doesn't cause a `CHECKPOINT` operation on the databases, it does flush out the procedure cache. If you restart the instance just to change memory settings, not only will the procedure cache be cold, but the data cache will be cold, too. If the max memory cannot be reduced because of dirty pages in memory, run the `CHECKPOINT` command on the databases to flush the dirty pages to disk, then change the memory setting at off-peak time _without_ restarting the instance.