# Do indexes consume memory?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am just starting to learn about memory usage on SQL Server.  When using the query in the answer to the question [SQL Server 2008 R2 "Ghost Memory"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7060/sql-server-2008-r2-ghost-memory), I discovered that a single database is taking up the lion's share of space in the buffer pool.  Looking further, using `sys.allocation_units` and `sys.indexes`, I confirmed this is likely caused by the heavy use of indexes in the database.  Most indexes are clustered.

Another database developer believes we are having memory issues on the server - that queries are starting to run long because there is no available memory.

My question here is - does the use of these indexes, and their existence in the buffer pool, take away memory available for other processes?

Comment: `"Another database developer believes we are having memory issues on the server"` -- based on what? How much RAM does the server have, what are the the instance memory settings, and how much memory is being consumed by the procedure cache?

Comment: Based on extended query times and looking at Task Manager - which my research has indicated is a "dirty, filthy liar" (thanks Brent Ozar - http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/09/sysadmins-guide-microsoft-sql-server-memory/).  I may find there is no memory issue - I'm following all suggestions provided in these comments and answers!

Comment: Since we're rolling the 8 ball here, I think the queries run slow because they were written by that 'another' database developer...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, **the data pages of a used index that are cached in the buffer pool will be taking up space in the data cache**.  But don't let that turn you away from using indexes (first off, a clustered index is the actual table data so keep that in mind as well).  The use of indexes (properly designed and implemented, of course) is a good thing.

*Your memory issues are most likely not from having indexes on your tables*.  Dive into the memory issues, what exactly are the problems?  Are you having a low *Page Life Expectancy*?  How is your memory configured on the server?  Is the max server memory to low restricting the size of the buffer pool?

To get a breakdown of the index pages in your data cache, you can run the below query:

```
select
    count(*) as total_page_count,
    count(*) * 8 as total_consumption_kb,
    sum(row_count) as total_row_count
from sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
where page_type = 'INDEX_PAGE'
group by page_type
```

To get these stats by database:

```
select
    db_name(database_id) as database_name,
    count(*) as total_page_count,
    count(*) * 8 as total_consumption_kb,
    sum(row_count) as total_row_count
from sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
where page_type = 'INDEX_PAGE'
group by database_id
order by total_consumption_kb desc
```

Comment: Decent (?) page life expectancy - 4234.  I need to research the buffer cache hit ratio and look into the other parts.

Comment: That PLE is not showing memory pressure at all.  Anything over 1000 as a rule of thumb (of course, there's always "it depends") is acceptable.

Comment: Buffer cache hit ratio can be very misleading, or out and out useless. See [Great SQL Server Debates: Buffer Cache Hit Ratio](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/great-sql-server-debates-buffer-cache-hit-ratio/) by @JonathanKehayias.

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith Noted, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @JHFB Let's take a step back.  What makes you think you are having memory pressure?

Comment: I'm going to formulate another question, since the specific question I asked here has been addressed.  Thanks, Shark!

Comment: @JHFB Ok, glad to help!  I'll check out that other question and see if I have any helpful input on that as well.

Answer (score 7):

Indexes consume buffer pool space, yes. This is one more reason why you should take care with your indexing strategy and minimise duplicates.

> I confirmed this is likely caused by the heavy use of indexes in the
>   database. Most indexes are clustered.

Remember that a clustered index *is the table*. The only overhead that exists for a clustered index over and above that for a heap (which is generally undesirable) is for the non-leaf index pages and the cluster key's inclusion in all non-clustered indexes for that table. This is why narrow cluster key's are preferred.

[Kimberley Tripp's articles on clustered key choices](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/Clustered-Index.aspx) are an excellent reference for this.