# SQL Server cluster questions please

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, clustering

We have SQL Server 2008 R2 cluster active/active/active (a, b, c) and three instances run on this environment.

We did a test on one of the instances, and failover test.

1. Manual failover from node c to b.  After 3 minutes, the application cannot connect to SQL Server.
2. Back to node c we are OK and application is happy
3. Manual failover from node c to a.  After 3 minutes, the application cannot connect to SQL Server.
4. Back to node c we are OK and application is happy

Please give me some helps.

Comment: Can you connect to the instance after failover?  If so, look in the SQL Server error log and see what is happening.  Could be a few things taking a long time (i.e. database recovery).  If you can't connect to the instance, take a look at the cluster log and look for errors/issues.

Comment: see my reply here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldisasterrecovery/thread/d368ec95-fec8-473e-9456-716ba4f68897 and mind telling us what's error received by application as looks like you don't know how to check cluster log.

Comment: @ThomasStringer I forgot about database recovery. That's a great point.

Comment: Also check to see if the passive nodes are possible owners of the instance.  What it boils down to is that there are a lot of things that could be causing this and either 1) you need to dig deeper into the problem and/or 2) provide us with more information and details.

Comment: Check your failover cluster manager critic events log for the nodes that aren´t running. What do they say?

Answer (score 6):

There are a few things that I can think of off the top of my head. You're running a multi-instance failover cluster so in theory I'd expect to see each node to be sized such that at any given point in time it can handle the load of *all three instances*. Chances are that this is not the case, but maybe it is. Ideally, you'd also have a spare node that can handle failures but that doesn't sound like it's the case here.

There are some configurations that you can check to ensure that you've not set yourself up for failure and the first one I'd check would be to run

```
sp_configure 'max server memory (MB)'
```

If your `run value` is `2147483647` then you've got it set to allow SQL Server to take as much memory as it thinks it needs. This is set ***per instance*** so when you have multiple instances trying to consume all available RAM you will get memory pressure.

*Having said that* (read: *actually, start here*), you've not given us any other information about what you've done to discover *why* the application stops responding. Is it just the application that connects to the `C` node that chokes, or does the original application also not work? This could end up being something as simple as the application connection string is connecting to the IP/DNS name of the `C` node and not the VIP. If this is the case, then when `C` is no longer serving SQL Server then you're not going to be able to connect.

Step 1: Ensure the connection strings are actually connecting to the instance/VIP name and not the nodes.

Step 1.5: (Thanks to Thomas Stringer), make sure that you're giving the new instance enough time to actually recover the database. Connect to the ***instance*** via SSMS and see if your databases are in recovery.

Step 2: If Step 1 is correct, then get on the node that is running multiple instances and see what's going on. I'd recommend using PerfMon because ["Task Manager is a dirty, filthy liar"](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/09/sysadmins-guide-microsoft-sql-server-memory/) and looking at metrics for the various subsystems starting with Memory, Network, CPU, and Disk IO. [This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7062/4490) contains much of what you'd need in order to check for resource pressure ***assuming you have connectivity to the instance and the databases are all fully recovered***.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies.
From the application site, I had the error message: "EODBC Error Text: [IBM][SQLServer JDBC Driver]The requested instance is either invalid or not running."

According to the staff who manage the cluster environment, it seems to me that the C node is the only good one and all of three instances is running on this node.

After the manual failover, we could connect to the SQL instance from SSMS.  About 3 or 4 minutes later we could not see.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that you believe all 3 instances are running on the C node, or is that what the DBAs told you?

Comment: Yes. I believe so.

Comment: Have you been able to confirm this with your DBA team? Do you have access to the instance(s) with SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: I did try and after 3-4 minutes i could not connect to the instance.

Comment: Ok. And you're sure you're not actually connecting to the node itself? You're connecting to the SQL Server instance, right? Can you connect to the other instances?

Comment: No.  I connect to the SQL instance.  And I didn't try to connect to other instances.

Answer (score 0):

There may be problem in port allocation. If more then one instance running on single server OS gives separate ports for each instance other then 1433 (default port). To resolve the issue go to SQL Server Configuration Manager TCP/IP change to fix port and give a port number the (TCP/IP) Network provided. And use same port number in connection string of your web application.

Server = IP Addr/Instance Name Port = Given Port No. Uid = MyUid Pwd = MyPwd